# After the first run, all is NaN

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, nan, var

Im  new her and starting to learn JavaScript. One of my first Projects is a game with two dices. You have two players, an each player has 100$ for the start. You can bet for each round, and if you winn, the money goes to you. Now the problem is: The first round ist okay, and the money goes to the winner pocket, but if i want to start the secont bet round, All var's are NaN. I know that i have to write the script in external files, also the css, but this was only a trial for me.I tries to check if (isNaN)  but it dosent work. Thank you very much

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Würfelspiel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Würfel.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.8, user-scalable=no">
    </head>
    <body style=" background-image: linear-gradient(to right, green, darkgreen)">
        <center><h1 style="font-family: Broadway">Würfelspiel</h1></center>
       <h3 style="padding-left: 600px; padding-top: 100px; ">Drücke auf den Würfel und versuche dein Glück</h3>
        <center> <p id="gewinn" style="font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: large"></p></center>

        <center><input  id="wetteinsatz" type="text"></center>


        <p id="guthaben1" style=" float: right"></p><br><br><br>
        <p id="guthaben2" style=" float: right"></p><br><br><br>
        <button onclick="wette()" style="float: right">Wette Abgeben</button>



      <div id="out" onclick="würfel()" style="box-sizing: border-box; margin-right: 150px; float: left; border-radius: 50px; margin-top: 200px; margin-left: 100px;
            background-color: #0a8c04; padding-left: 350px; padding-right: 250px; padding-top: 244px; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat;
             background-image: url(würfel_1.png)"></div><br><br><br>

      <div id="out1" onclick="würfel1()" style="box-sizing: border-box;; margin-left: 900px; margin-right: 90px; margin-top: 155px; background-color: #0a8c04;
            padding-right: ; padding-top: 240px; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; margin-bottom: 150px; border-radius:
                 50px; background-image: url(würfel_1.png)"></div>


        <div class="wrap">
    <div class="cube">
        <div class="front"></div>
        <div class="back"></div>
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>


<a href="https://diereiseritter.com/" style=" color: rgba(234, 127, 11, 0.72); font-family: 'Playlist Script'; font-size: xx-large">By DieReiseRitter</a>

       <script>
           function prüfenNaN() {
               if (isNaN(Pott)) {
                   Pott = 0;
               } else if (isNaN(guthaben1parse)) {
                   guthaben1parse = 100;
               } else if (isNaN(guthaben2parse)) {
                   guthaben2parse = 100;
               }
           }

           //###########################################################################
           //##### Start mit Guthaben
           //###########################################################################

           var guthaben1 = 100
           guthaben1parse = Number.parseInt(guthaben1);
           document.getElementById('guthaben1').innerHTML = 'Spieler 1 Guthaben: ' + guthaben1parse + '$';

           var guthaben2 = 100
           guthaben2parse = Number.parseInt(guthaben2);
           document.getElementById('guthaben2').innerHTML = 'Spieler 2 Guthaben: ' + guthaben2parse + '$';



           //##################################
           //###### Funktion zum erstellen eines Gewinners
           //##################################

           function gewinn() {
               u = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
               document.getElementById('gewinn').innerHTML = 'Der Gewinner Würfelt ' + u;



           }

           function einschreiben2() {

               guthaben2parse = guthaben2parse + Pott;
               guthaben2parse = Number.parseInt(guthaben2parse);
               document.getElementById('guthaben2').innerHTML = 'Spieler 2 Guthaben: ' + guthaben2parse + '$';
               return guthaben2parse;

           }



           function einschreiben1() {

               guthaben1parse = guthaben1parse + Pott;
               guthaben1parse = Number.parseInt(guthaben1parse);
               document.getElementById('guthaben1').innerHTML = 'Spieler 1 Guthaben: ' + guthaben1parse + '$';
               return guthaben1parse;
           }



           function Pottdel() {
               Pott = 0;
               document.getElementById('wetteinsatz').value = '';
           }

           //######################################################################################
           //###### Funktion Wett Button
           //#####################################################################################

           function wette() {




               // Einsatz
               wetteinsatz1 = window.prompt('Spieler 1 ihren Wetteinsatz bitte');
               wetteinsatz1parse = Number.parseInt(wetteinsatz1);

               wetteinsatz2 = window.prompt('Spieler 2 ihren Wetteinsatz bitte');
               wetteinsatz2parse = Number.parseInt(wetteinsatz2);

               // Zieht Einsatz von Guthaben ab
               guthaben1parse = guthaben1parse - wetteinsatz1parse;
               guthaben2parse = guthaben2parse - wetteinsatz2parse;

               // Schreibt neues Guthaben in den Paragraphen
               document.getElementById('guthaben1').innerHTML = 'Spieler 1 Guthaben: ' + guthaben1parse + '$';
               document.getElementById('guthaben2').innerHTML = 'Spieler 2 Guthaben: ' + guthaben2parse + '$';

               // Schreibt Pott in Wetteinsatz Feld
               Pott = wetteinsatz1parse + wetteinsatz2parse;
               Pott = Number.parseInt(Pott);
               document.getElementById('wetteinsatz').value = 'Der Pott liegt bei ' + Pott + '$';

               prüfenNaN();
           }







           //##############################
           //###### Ruft die Gewinnfunktion auf und schreibt sie in den Paragraphen
           //##############################

           gewinn();

           //##############################
           //###### Spieler Links Funtion für Zufällige Würfelzahl
           //##############################

           function würfel() {

               //#####################
               //#### Audio Variable erstellen und Abspielen
               //#####################
               var snd = new Audio("roll.wav");
               snd.play();

               //#####################
               //#### Alarmausgabe bei Wurf
               //#####################
               window.alert('Die Würfel Rollen!');

               //#####################
               //######Erzeugt Zufällige Zahl zwischen 1 und 6
               //#####################

               wurf = Math.round(Math.random() * 6) + 1


               //#####################
               //#### Bei Gewürfelter Zahl, wird Bild eingefügt
               //#####################

               if (wurf == 0) {

                   document.getElementById('out').style.backgroundImage = 'url(würfel_1.png)';

               } else if (wurf == 1) {
                   document.getElementById('out').style.backgroundImage = 'url(würfel_1.png)';

               } else if (wurf == 2) {
                   document.getElementById('out').style.backgroundImage = 'url(würfel_2.png)';

               } else if (wurf == 3) {
                   document.getElementById('out').style.backgroundImage = 'url(würfel_3.png)';

               } else if (wurf == 4) {
                   document.getElementById('out').style.backgroundImage = 'url(würfel_4.png)';
               } else if (wurf == 5) {
                   document.getElementById('out').style.backgroundImage = 'url(würfel_5.png)';
               } else if (wurf == 6) {
                   document.getElementById('out').style.backgroundImage = 'url(würfel_6.png)';
               }



               //####################
               //#### Wenn var wurf und u (variable in der gewinn funktion) gleich sind, ausgabe Sieg
               //#################### 
               if (wurf == u) {
                   var tada = new Audio("Tada.mp3");
                   tada.play();
                   window.alert('Spieler Eins hat gewonnen');
                   gewinn();

                   einschreiben1();
                   Pottdel();
               }
           }



           //##############################
           //###### Spieler Rechts Funtion für Zufällige Würfelzahl
           //##############################
           function würfel1() {



               //#####################
               //#### Audio Variable erstellen und Abspielen
               //#####################
               var snd = new Audio("roll.wav");
               snd.play();

               //#####################
               //#### Alarmausgabe bei Wurf
               //#####################
               window.alert('Die Würfel Rollen!');

               //#####################
               //######Erzeugt Zufällige Zahl zwischen 1 und 6
               //#####################

               wurf1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 6) + 1


               //#####################
               //#### Bei Gewürfelter Zahl, wird Bild eingefügt
               //#####################
               if (wurf1 == 0) {

                   document.getElementById('out1').style.backgroundImage = 'url(würfel_1.png)';

               } else if (wurf1 == 1) {
                   document.getElementById('out1').style.backgroundImage = 'url(würfel_1.png)';

               } else if (wurf1 == 2) {
                   document.getElementById('out1').style.backgroundImage = 'url(würfel_2.png)';

               } else if (wurf1 == 3) {
                   document.getElementById('out1').style.backgroundImage = 'url(würfel_3.png)';

               } else if (wurf1 == 4) {
                   document.getElementById('out1').style.backgroundImage = 'url(würfel_4.png)';
               } else if (wurf1 == 5) {
                   document.getElementById('out1').style.backgroundImage = 'url(würfel_5.png)';
               } else if (wurf1 == 6) {
                   document.getElementById('out1').style.backgroundImage = 'url(würfel_6.png)';
               }

               //####################
               //#### Wenn var wurf1 und u (variable in der gewinn funktion) gleich sind, ausgabe Sieg
               //#################### 

               if (wurf1 == u) {
                   var tada = new Audio("Tada.mp3");
                   tada.play();
                   window.alert('Spieler Zwei hat gewonnen');
                   gewinn();

                   einschreiben2();
                   Pottdel()
               }

           }














       </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you see that `All var's are NaN` ? I played a bit around, and I could see no NaN. Also, this is waaaay too much code. Please try to narrow down to a specific problem. Just dumping your whole app's code is too much :/

Comment: Tip : the whole `Bei Gewürfelter Zahl, wird Bild eingefügt` 15-line if-else block could be replaced by this one line : `out.style.backgroundImage = \`url(würfel_${ wurf + 1 }.png)\`;`

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the tip. Im a bloody noob in coding. i will try your short way to put the png's in the program. In the input field at id="wetteinsatz" and the <p> id="guthaben1" and also at <p> id='guthaben2' is NaN when i tries to play the second round.

Comment: Yes I know it's a lot of code here, but i didn't know where i have to search the failure sorry. Its my first time here.

Comment: Well, the first step to debug is to add `console.log(stuff)` here and there, and see what it outputs in the console. Then you can understand what happens and narrow down the problem.

Comment: Also, for your question, you could remove all irrelevant stuff : everything related to tada.mp3, everything related to setting the background image. There's few chances that the problem is in there :)

Comment: Okay, I go from start, and put console.log() where I think the problem can sit in. Thanks for your time. Greetings from Cyprus.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Greetings from France :)